# Proving z+|z| is continuous

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how to show that complex functions are continuous.  I seem to be struggling to understand exactly how to show continuity here.  It doesn't help that trying to imagine complex functions as a whole is challenging.  Anyways, I am looking to show that z+|z| is continuous.  I believe I am looking for a neighborhood $$N_{\epsilon}(f(z_0))$$ that contains my initial $$z_0$$ but I'm not sure I'm fully understanding the formula, $$f(N_{\delta}(z_0)) \subseteq N_{\epsilon}(f(z_0))$$  I believe this neighborhood would be $$|z_0|$$ since our $$z_0$$ will always be contained in $$N_{|z_0|}$$  But I'm not sure I'm thinking about this right.  Can someone please help me understand this better?

Comment: What is the definition of continuity that you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$|(z+|z|)-(w+|w|)| =$$

$$ |(z-w) +(|z|-|w|)\le$$

$$ |z-w|+||z|-|w||\le 2|z-w|$$

Thus for a given $\epsilon >0$, it suffices to have your $\delta = \frac {\epsilon }{2}$

Then $$|z-w|<\delta \implies |(z+|z|)-(w+|w|)|<\epsilon.$$

Thus the function is continuous.